# python dictionary- two keys to each value

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I am fairly sure you can't do this but I was wondering if you could have a dictionary where each of the values can be accessed via two keys without duplicating the dictionary.

The reason I want to do this is that the two keys will represent the same thing but one will be a shortened version eg. 'TYR' and 'Y' will both have the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just place same (mutable) object in two places. If you change the object it will change in both places in the dictionary. Only donwside is that you have to add and delete both explicitly (you could create some helper method though).

```
In [4]: d = {}
In [5]: c = [1,2]
In [7]: d[1] = c
In [8]: d[2] = c
In [9]: d
Out[9]: {1: [1, 2], 2: [1, 2]}
In [10]: c.append(3)
In [11]: d
Out[11]: {1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3]}
```

If you want to store unmutable types like string and tuple, you probably need to create object that will store in them and change it inside that object.

Comment: All objects only store a reference. You could do `d = {1: (1, 2, 3)}` then `d[2] = d[1]`. The mutability is irrelevant.

Comment: @agf Changed the wording a bit as I've read your previous comment. The thing with the tuple stored like that is you can't change one in a way that would change it in both places, can you?

Comment: You can't change it at all, correct. The fact that you can do things that look like changing it might confuse the OP, true, but that's really a different issue from whether you duplicate an object when you store it twice in a `dict`.